# SheetJS exported excel file showing improper dates and string values are reduced to scientific notations

Tags: javascript, xlsx, sheetjs

I am trying to export my html table to excel file, using *SheetJS* library. This is my code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.2/xlsx.full.min.js" ></script>

<script>
    var a = document.getElementById("new_table");
    var fp=XLSX.utils.table_to_book(a,{sheet:"table"});
    XLSX.write(fp,{
                   bookType:'xlsx',
                   type:'base64'
              });
    XLSX.writeFile(fp,"table.xlsx");
</script>
```

My `html` table has a column called *dates* where all the dates are in string, i.e., 10/04/2021, 11/05/2021, etc. and another column called *ID* where all the values are 11 digit string, i.e., 11P02399018, etc.

But in my **table.xlsx** file, the IDs are shown in scientific notation and the dates are showing as ######. When I hover over the the ##### value, the date is like 04-10-2021, 05-11-2021, etc. Why? How do I fix this?

Moreover in ID such as 01480EI2104, the preceding 0 is removed in the excel file, i.e., it becomes 1480EI2104.

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are showing as ######, that means your columns are not wide enough to fit the content. You could open the file and make those columns wider, or you can do it with code:

```
ws['!cols'] = wscols
```

Where `ws` is the worksheet and `wscols` is an array of column properties objects, like this: `{wch: 18}`

See: [worksheet-object](https://github.com/sheetjs/sheetjs#worksheet-object)